# Close DockableControlPane with keyboard input

Tags: c#, infragistics

I'm working on a project that uses Infragistic controls.  It creates a `UserControl` that is puts into a `DockableControlPane` that is then put into a `DockAreaPane` that is inside of a `UltraDockManager` that is inside a `Form`.  When one of these `DockableControlPane`s are undocked and have focus I need a way to capture a key press that will allow me to close that "window".  The problem I'm having is that there doesn't seem to be any keyboard events made public by the Infragistic controls.  I've overriden `OnKeyUp` in my main form and it captures key presses when all the child windows are docked, but not if one is floating and in focus.  I've tried to override `OnKeyUp` in the control inside the `DockableControlPane`, but that never gets called.  I'm at a complete loss as to where I can consistently capture key presses in these floating windows, or some setting that will enable a keyboard shortcut to close them.  At this point I'm not too picky on what keyboard shortcut will do the job.  And switching away from Intragistics is not a viable option.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to handle this by adding a hidden button to the `UltraToolbarsManager`, which in my case was what was swallowing the keyboard input, and setting it's shortcut to Ctrl-F4.

Answer (score 0):

You can override ProcessCmdKey of the Form Class:

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        switch (keyData)
        {
            // open panel combination keys  Ctrl + F
            case (Keys.Control | Keys.F):
                if (this.ultraDockManager1.ControlPanes["Your Pane Name"] != null)
                    if (this.ultraDockManager1.ControlPanes["Your Pane Name"].Pinned)
                    {
                        this.ultraDockManager1.ControlPanes["Your Pane Name"].Pinned = false;
                    }
                    else if (this.ultraDockManager1.ControlPanes["Your Pane Name"].IsInView)
                    {
                        this.ultraDockManager1.FlyIn(false);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        // this.ultraDockManager1.ControlPanes["Your Pane Name"].Pin();
                        this.ultraDockManager1.ControlPanes["Your Pane Name"].Activate();
                    }
         }
    }
```

Maybe for the next one :D